# Double-clicking on a form control in Visual Studio 2010 design view inserts a script instead of inserting an event handler

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

The title pretty much precisely asks the question, but I shall repeat;

When I double click on a form control while in the design view in a Web Application project within Visual Studio 2010, say a 'button' or a 'submit' for example, it inserts a javascript function into my .aspx file.  When I do this at work it automatically creates an event handler for the control in the code-behind.

How do I change this to that setting?  I have used '/resetsettings' already, and other answers to similar questions do not solve my problem.  I have reinstalled, gone through every menu I can find (though I may have missed something) and I'm pulling my hair out.

I don't want to type those event handler subroutines every time!  Halp meee!

Thanks in advance for any helpful replies.

Comment: I have never encountered that... can you include a screenshot or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it looks like is going on with this is that you are double clicking on a regular HTML element. For example, if you have

```
<input type="button" value="Test" id="Test" name="Test" />
```

and double click on it in design view it will create a JavaScript function on the page for it and an onclick event in the element. If you want to create an event handler in the code behind, you need to have an Asp.Net control like

`<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Test" Text="Test" />`

and then double click that to create a code event in the code behind.

Also, make sure that your page directive at the top has the correct filename for its `CodeFile` attribute to correctly map to an existing code behind file.

Comment: You are correct, moriartyn!  Sorry for not responding sooner, but I had to go to sleep ^^

Comment: @Dan Rayson Glad I could help figure it out. If that got everything working for you, I would appreciate it if you could mark the green check mark as the answer, but only if it answered the question correctly.

Comment: In case anyone else ends up here, the double-click will also not add code-behind if the solution is running!