# Double-clicking on a form in Visual Studio 2013 view inserts a script in my html page instead of inserting an event handler in the c# page

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Please I need help. Below is what is injected in my code when I double click my submit button on the design page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Tutorial.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server">

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 115%;
            height: 415px;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 541px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            height: 73px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            height: 44px;
        }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table class="auto-style1">
```

Comment: This is a story about what happened when you did something; what is your question?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10507070/4347337

Comment: Okay, please how I prevent this from happening? A double click should lead to my c# page and not to an html page. Any suggestions?